# Ansible conditional based on contents of file

Tags: python, ansible

Gratefully if someone could point out what's wrong with this…

The following code is meant to setup a test in the register module that prints the current value of `/etc/timezone`.  There's then a task that compares that to the group/host {{ timezone }} variable and only runs the task if it's different (i.e. doesn't call handlers unnecessarily).

But it always runs regardless.

```
- name: check current timezone
  shell: cat /etc/timezone
  register: get_timezone

- name: set /etc/timezone
  shell: echo "{{ timezone }}" > /etc/timezone
  when: get_timezone.stdout.find('{{ timezone }}') == false
  notify: update tzdata
```

....

in group_vars/all.yml:

```
timezone: Europe/London
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Python string.find method returns -1 if it can't find the substring (https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html, see string.find). So, you could modify your yml like that:

```
- name: set /etc/timezone
  shell: echo "{{ timezone }}" > /etc/timezone
  when: get_timezone.stdout.find('{{ timezone }}') == -1
  notify: update tzdata
```

or just use "not in":

```
- name: set /etc/timezone
  shell: echo "{{ timezone }}" > /etc/timezone
  when: '"{{ timezone }}" not in get_timezone.stdout'
  notify: update tzdata
```

Comment: In latest ansible such `not in` can produce warning. So better to use such cause `when: 'timezone | string not in get_timezone.stdout'`

Comment: The annoying thing is that **find()** is not documented in Ansible docks. So unless you are failiar with Python functions you are forced to use 'in / not in' which not always works the same way as the **find()**